# while installing hadoop i did the conf part and all after that when i typed hadoop version in cmd it is giving java version

Tags: hadoop

```
C:\Users\91842>hadoop -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.91-b15, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Seems like you managed to `alias hadoop=java`